# Не работает самовыгрузка dll

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Я хочу, чтобы при внешнем присоединении DLL я мог ее отсоединить из самой dll. Но сделать это из самой dll невозможно, поэтому я выделяю память под структуру, в которой содержится адрес функции `FreeLibrary` и хендл модуля, который надо выгрузить. Так же выделяю память под функцию потока, которая и будет выгружать эту dll. Всё работает до момента вызова самой функции, `FreeLibrary` возвращает 1, то есть все хорошо. Но если посмотреть на загруженные модули, то dll не выгрузилась. Рабочий ли это метод и в чем проблема?

Код dll:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "winternl.h"
#include <process.h>


DWORD GetProcId(const char* procname)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    HANDLE hSnap;

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe)) {
        do {
            if (strcmp(pe.szExeFile, procname) == 0)
                break;
        } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe));
    }
    return pe.th32ProcessID;
}

struct packet {
    HMODULE hModule;
    DWORD64 addrFunc;
};
packet pck;

DWORD __stdcall RemoteThread(void* stack) //thread that will be spawned in our target process
{
    typedef bool(_stdcall* FreeLib)(_In_ HMODULE hLibModule);
    FreeLib MyFreeLibrarry = (FreeLib)((packet*)stack)->addrFunc;
    bool result=FreeLib(HMODULE(((packet*)stack)->hModule));
    std::cout << "result: " <<result<< std::endl; // result: 1

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void MainThread(void* stack)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "MainThread..." <<std::endl;
        Sleep(100);

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x74)) //f5
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetProcId("target.exe"));
            LPVOID pRemoteThread = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, SIZE_T(512), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteThread, (LPVOID)RemoteThread, SIZE_T(512), 0);

            LPVOID PtrPacket = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL,sizeof(packet), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, PtrPacket, stack, sizeof(packet), 0);

            CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)RemoteThread, PtrPacket, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}



BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        HMODULE kernel32 = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
        pck.hModule = hModule;
        pck.addrFunc= (DWORD64)GetProcAddress(kernel32, "FreeLibrary");
    
        _beginthread(MainThread, sizeof(pck), &pck);
    }
     return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте инжектить трэд в другой процесс (типа Explorer.exe), а он уже будет инжектить трэд с выгрузкой в ваш процесс.

Comment: @Dmitry Sokolov а зачем так?Почему нельзя инжектить поток выгрузки в процесс в котором находится dll? Так даже удобнее,мы можем использовать все winapi функции,ведь они одинаковые в одном процессе

Comment: Возможно, есть какие-то оптимизации.

Comment: А вы для начала для отладки проверьте, вызывается ли в вашей библиотеке точка входа в библиотеку с параметром выгрузки... `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Answer (score 1):

Много чего тут может пойти не так.
Некоррестные предположения:

1. HMODULE в процессе, откуда вызывается eject и в целевом процессе сопадают. Это не всегда так, особенно с базовым адресом DLL по умолчанию.
2. `std::cout` будет работать. В конечном итоге это DLL вызов (рантайм DLL, либо системной для статического рантайма), перенесенный через `WriteProcessMemory` код правильно отработает только если своей DLL повезло загрузиться в другом процессе по тому же адресу.
3. Код `RemoteThread` не требует релокаций. Вероятно, но не гарантированно для x64, маловероятно для 32-битной x86. Опять же всё будет работать, если DLL загрузится в другой процесс по тому же адресу.
4. Код `RemoteThread` одним сплошным куском. это вероятно, но не гаратнируется (также не факт, что влезет в 512 байт)
5. Адрес kernel32.FreeLibrary совпадает между процессами. Обычно это так, но возможны исключения (по крайней мере, когда один из x64 процессов `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, другой нет)
6. DllMain можно безопасно вызывать `_beginthreadex`.
7. `FreeLibrary` выгружает при успехе. Она уменьшает счёт ссылок DLL, т.е. если он не стал равен 0, то выгрузка не произойдёт. Если DLL была pinned `GetModuleHandleEx` с `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN`, то она вообще выгружена не будет.

Судя по тому, что код как-то работает, я допускаю предположение, что `hProcess` может оказываться на самом деле текущим процессом, т.е. Remote Thread вовсе не Remote.